# What does "go with" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, american-english

People rate how close they feel to one another on a scale of 1 to 10
and someone says "I'll go with a 5".

I understand it loosely but I want to know its precise meaning as a native speaker feels.

Comment: It means something like I think it's about a five.  To me it kind of sounds like the person wasn't completely sure. It could have been a five or it could have been something else. That's my sense of it.

Comment: @RichardKayser I kind of make sense of it, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does that mean you'll go with it? :-) It could also mean that the person likes five as the answer and is sure. It's subtle. Depends on context.

Answer (score 1):

It means that "I feel comfortable with choosing 5". It's not as direct and decisive as a straight "5" answer, but it does mean that this is what he chooses.

Comment: I got it, thnaks a lot!